# Symbol conventions regarding regions of integration and differentials

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, soft-question, notation

Concerning notation; double integrals are commonly expressed as $\iint_R\,f\,dA$ where $R$ is a region in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $dA=dx\,dy$ is ‘an infinitesimal partition’ of R. For surface integrals, $\iint_σ\,f\,dS$ and $\iint_S\,f\,dΣ$ are common. For line integrals, $\int_\mathcal{C}\,f\,ds$, etcetera.

$$
\begin{matrix}
R & dA \\
σ & dS \\
S & dΣ \\
\mathcal{C} & ds \\
D & dV
\end{matrix}
$$

As a learner, I am tempted to name the differentials after the regions themselves (like $\iint_A\,f\,dA$, $\iint_S\,f\,dS$, $\iiint_V\,f\,dV$) because, to me, that seems simpler and employs fewer distinct symbols. The $dX$ is simply interpreted as ‘a piece of $X$’. Even if one has two different regions—say $R$ and $Q$—using corresponding differentials $dR$ and $dQ$ (as opposed to both $dA$) seems clearer to me, so long as the regions are understood to be regions.

What is the rationale is for using different symbols? Is there any reason not to use the same?

Answer (score 1):

Much of it is convention, and if you go on to study deeper or research then knowing the conventions of your field becomes important.  Using the "wrong" symbol will confuse or annoy other people, and occasionally cause real problems because they've interpreted the symbol in the conventional way as opposed to the way you intended.

**A** stands for Area, **S** for Surface, **V** for Volume so they're not entirely unintuitive (for English-speakers).  **$\Sigma$** is a "Greek S" (it's all kinds of wrong to say that but it's a good-enough approximation here) and is conventional for surfaces as well.  Not all our conventions are from English: an $F_\sigma$ set is a countable union of closed sets where $F$ stands for the French **Fermé** and the $\sigma$ is for countable (ok, so this goes back to Hausdorff who used $s$ for finitely summable and then switched to the greek letter for countably summable, so there is a sense there).

As with all notation though, provided you're clear about what you're doing and consistent with it people will understand.